# Cinnamon crashing on Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 AWS instance

Tags: 18.04, vnc, cinnamon, amazon-ec2, vncviewer

I have an issue with Cinnamon on Ubuntu 18 - EC2 AWS.
Cinnamon is crashing whatever I do, see picture bellow:

[image: Cinnamon just crashed. You are currently running in a fallback mode]

```
$ sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment lightdm
$ sudo apt install tightvncserver
$ sudo apt-get install libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5  (this is to fix PAM issue on lightdm)
```

```
$ cinnamon --version
Cinnamon 3.6.7
```

```
$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: Cirrus Logic GD 5446 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: N/A drivers: vesa (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev)
           tty size: 120x34 Advanced Data: N/A out of X
```

```
$vi ~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
cinnamon-session &
```

[image: lightdm is fine, no errors]

Answer (score 0):

Found solution>

It is problem with tightvncserver.

Install this one instead >
sudo apt install tigervnc-standalone-server tigervnc-common